# IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with my asp.net site since upgrading to net7.0.

I load a pdf into my temp directory and want to attach it to an e-mail.

```
        // upload invoice to computer
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var responseStream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync("..site.com/.../uploads/" + invoice.PfadRel + "");
        using var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\Invoice-" + invoice.no + ".pdf", FileMode.Create, (FileAccess)FileShare.ReadWrite);
        responseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);

        // attach invoice to mail
        builder.Attachments.Add(@"C:\Temp\Invoice-" + invoice.no + ".pdf");
```

Unfortunately the line with "builder.Attachments." generates the error message:

```
IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Does anyone have any idea what went wrong here?

Comment: Add curly braces around the copy: `using (var fileStream = ...) { CopyTo(...) }`.

Comment: Mind you that "another process" could also be your own process. Also, it is generally helpful when you provide the complete stacktrace of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

@CodeMaster: this was the hint.

This solved my problem:

```
        using var fileStream = new FileStream... ;
        {
            responseStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            fileStream.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: `using` makes sure `Dispose` is automatically called at the end, so no need to call it explicitly.